# Why can't I use vanilla javascript (eventlistener) in AngularJS link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I was just testing some stuff and I was writing a directive like this:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <my-directive>
        hi {{name}}
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("app", [])

.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        scope:true,
        restrict: "E",
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.name="yourname";
            elem.onclick = function () { console.log("change name");}
        }

    }
})
```

But the onclick function never fires. And I know this is not how I should properly write in Angular, but it was just something I did on the fly. However, this works:

```
angular.module("app", [])

.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        scope:true,
        restrict: "E",
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

            scope.name="yourname";
            elem.on("click", function () {console.log("change name")});
        }

    }
})
```

And here a fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghkfjjh6/8/)

What is going on here? Is it outside the Angular world and should I use `scope.apply`or something to get it to work. I am just curious why vanilla javascript is not ok in this case. But this is also a good lesson to keep myself focused on thinking the Angular way.

Maybe someone that can explain what is going on?
TIA

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work for me, but I would expect you need to do elem[0].onclick - since elem is a jqLite-wrapped object.

Comment: Aside: you're doing `restrict: "E"` but your markup is using it as an `attribute`, or `restrict: "A"`  -- **Edit:** your question is right, your fiddle is wrong.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hah .. I was looking at the question, checked the element/attribute thing, looked right and then didn't notice it in the jsfiddle :)

Comment: With Restrict E, the link function never executes.

Comment: @Mark - It is not correct. I think you should take a look at the directive documentation.

Comment: given the declaration <div my-directive> I updated the fiddle to have a Console.log call in the link function and it never logs to the console when it is set to Restrict E.  However if its set to Restrict A then it does.  Restrict E = link function doesn't run  .... with Restrict A, the link function does run. It's not debatable, this is how it works.

Comment: the fiddle is different from the code here ... that's probably where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Yes, I'm working from the original fiddle.

Comment: @all above, whoops...sorry, I have made a new fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `elem` inside link function is a jQuery object. You should get the html dom element using `elem[0]` and then try.

```
angular.module("app", [])

.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        scope:true,
        restrict: "E",
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.name="yourname";
            elem[0].onclick = function () { console.log("change name");}
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer I was looking for. It was not clear to me at all that `elem` was a jQuery object and so I guess `attr` is also a jQuery object?

Comment: `attr` is an object containing all the attributes key/value pair provided in the directive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new fiddle that gets your original code working, but the code in the question looks very different now.

One problem was your "name" property wasn't binding because you had an isolate scope where name was being set, but then transclude: true was causing angular to bind against an outer scope, so the name never displayed.  Also there was no template that was pulling in the transcluded content, leaving you with an empty html element.  This new fiddle is mostly your original code but the event handler works without going straight to the dom element as in the other posted answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/ghkfjjh6/9/

```
angular.module("app", [])

.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: "A",
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            console.log("link ran!");
            scope.name = "miek";
            console.log(scope);
           elem.on('mouseenter', function() {
               console.log("entered");
            })
        }

    }
})

<div ng-app="app">
    <div my-directive>
        hi {{name}}!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I appreciate your help, but I posted the wrong fiddle. The question was right, the fiddle was wrong. Sorry about that. See accepted answer for my original problem.

Comment: Ok, so your question doesn't require doing a transclude?

Comment: It seems like soon, you are going to realize the event handler works but the directive ultimately doesn't do what you want, but maybe not. I just figured it was supposed to use transclusion as well as have event handlers.

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. I am trying to go in depth with directives so I fiddle around with everything and sometimes I loose track of what fiddle I made.